# Scroll to a text position in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a real-time HTML editor, with a textarea on the left for code entry, and a 'preview' DIV on the right to contain the preview of the code entered. At the moment, when editing the code in the left pane, the preview just sits where it is, so often the part of the code you're editing is not in the visible area of the preview (especially when images are involved).

My question is how do I make the preview scroll to show the part of the code that's currently being edited?

Here is the page I have so far:
http://www.caerphoto.com/rtedit.html
You'll notice in the source I have a (currently unused) matchPreview() function that tries to match the scroll position of the preview based on the scroll position of the textarea, but obviously if images or large text are involved the two panes no longer match.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a div from the clone target try using a  tag.

Answer (score 0):

let me decompose your task into 2 subtasks:

1. get informed when the dom changes
   you could listen on changes of the dom like onsubtreemodified.

see
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events

2. scroll the element into view

the answer to this is the scrollintoview method:

see
www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/scrollintoview.html

however, this might not help you too much, since you are updating the whole html document on every change of the textarea.  since you cannot get the position of the cursor inside the textarea, this might be not that easy.

sorry mate, at the end I have no solution, but maybe my rumination helps in some way nevertheless.

good luck!

Comment: I found a semi-solution using some jquery magic:

    var jqselector = "#preview :contains('" + esced + "'):last";

This only works if the cursor is outside a tag, but it's the best I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this in Firefox. no line-breaks were seen in the preview; is this correct? I may be able to help (*done something similsr recently*), but not if the line breaks are removed...